# To answer or not: What makes the difference?

Tags: discussion, community, motivation

The statistics show that Stack Exchange family websites have a lot of users. For example, Stack Overflow has more than 14M users.

However, it seems that the majority of answers come from only a little percentage of users. I think that the majority of users just tend to visit the website, ask their questions, and leave shortly after receiving their answers.

I just wonder why it is like this. I want to know what motivates and demotivates users to make contributions for questions that are posed by someone else they don't know.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42481/294691

Comment: Re: "*This means that the majority of users just tend to visit the website, ask their questions, and leave shortly after receiving their answers.*"- I think this is too much of an assumption to make on such ambiguous data. It disregards all the other reasons accounts may go inactive, and assumes that every non-active account is apparently by users who got what they came for and left for selfish reasons.

Comment: The majority of users lands on a page due to a search engine hit, ideally gets something valuable out of it, and ***leaves without a trace*** (except for increasing a view counter).

Comment: @zcoop98 'assumes that every non-active account' - the OP wrote 'majority', not 'all'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

About a year ago, I wrote [something about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334785/295232) under different circumstances in answer to a different question: **Why do you stay?** (on Stack Exchange):

> #### Sharing knowledge is addictive
>
> I should have known about the addictiveness; when I'm at the office, I'm getting all kinds of questions from colleagues asking to explain how X works or how to solve problem Y. That often happens at inconvenient moments, like when I'm fully focused on another complicated problem. Still, being that Person That Knows Everything is tremendously gratifying.
>
> You can be that person on Stack Exchange as well, and most importantly: you can turn it off when it's not convenient for you! I'm aware that this holds true for all online communities (and even some offline ones) but here I feel my contributions have the most value for people around the world. I joined Stack Overflow because I noticed it saved me and my colleagues countless hours of work, more than any of the other programming sites. I wanted to give something back and be part of that awesome community producing high quality solutions.

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons to provide answers.

One reason is the warm fuzzy feeling you get knowing that you've helped someone out and answered their question; it's the same reason you stop to help someone in the street.

Another reason is, well, for the gamification. Stack gamifies pretty extensively; the current Winter Bash activity aside, you earn points and badges for answering and getting votes. That can turn out to be pretty addicting.

And once you're hooked, you start getting more and more involved in the site, and start editing, and flagging, and chatting... and get more and more invested.

Personally, I also use answers (and questions) as sort of practice for writing; writing on Stack Exchange - especially on Meta - has helped my writing skills extensively. When I had to write an essay for my high school graduation test, I just pretended I was writing a SE answer - and got a perfect score.

Answering is also a great way to *learn* stuff. If I'm researching random questions, trying to answer them, I end up learning a whole lot myself. (This is also applicable to asking.) It's a win-win situation.

So yeah, there are a whole lot of reasons why people stick around and write answers. A lot of people just don't see the draw, though, and that's also fine; not everybody needs to stick around and write answers if they don't want to.