# According to "Be part of the community that decides how the sites work" MSE is only about the SE software. Is that correct for 2024?

Tags: support, questions, meta, scope

According to the [tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour), to be part of this community, we should limit ourselves to asking questions about the "software that powers the Stack Exchange [network](https://stackexchange.com/sites)" and about questions related to **using** this *software*. Is this correct for 2024?

---

From the https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour, copied a few moments ago:

> ### Be part of the community that decides how the sites work
>
> ###### Ask about...
>
> Any question that has to do with the Stack Exchange family of communities is fair game.
>
> - Specific issues with the software that powers the Stack Exchange [network](https://stackexchange.com/sites)
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered using this software
>
> ###### However, you shouldn't ask about...
>
> While we discourage opinions on our main sites, questions here are likely to generate discussion and involve opinions. That's okay!
>
> - Anything not directly related to the software that powers the Stack Exchange [network](https://stackexchange.com/sites)
> - Questions that require the expertise of a specific Stack Exchange community - these should be asked on that site's meta instead

Comment: I feel like there’s really something else you’re wanting to ask about here, but you’re asking it in a roundabout way. What are you really getting at? Is there something going on the makes you think this site *isn’t* about SE software? It isn’t clear what you’re asking.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Thanks for your interest. Unfortunately, the software and the community that "powers" this "site" aren't well suited to... well, I don't know how to express this in such a way that is understood and well received by the audience of this place. Because of this, I try writing in a different way than I did in the past here. I'm a learner; if something didn't work for me in the past, I'm open to trying different things and appreciate the feedback a lot.

Comment: Slightly (?) related (created by me in 2019) : [Have we already had discussions about how to function more effectively in such a culturally diverse online community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336089/289691)

Comment: it feels like there's some underlying issue this question is trying to ask about without asking about it. Is the point really the emphasized "software" bit at the end? is the question whether or not "software" is correct anymore? something else?

Comment: Excuse my presumption, but when you say *"...questions related to using this software..."* are you referring to issues related to the platform's community culture?

Comment: @AugustoVasques I just paraphrased "Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered using this software"

Comment: What is the point of this XY question? Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: You know what we are talking about.

Comment: I'm not. If you don't want to help, it's OK.

Comment: It's not that we don't want to help you, please understand that as you are an experienced user of the platform, including a mod of one of our Q&A, we had the expectation by asking you in the comments your respective answers would be reflected in edits to your question clarifying the problem.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Thanks for replying. Please excuse me that I'm not a mind reader. So far, comments aren't clear to me about what the commenter is suggesting to be clarified in relation to the question's content. Your comment also looks to be biased based on whatever you have learned or think about me instead of focusing on the post content. Remember that feedback on questions and answers should be focused on the post, not on the user who has posted it. Also, remember that posts should not contain meta-commentary.

Comment: @Rubén Your question is obtuse and you are being obtuse in your comment replies. Just tell us why you’ve asked this question.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Please support your request on a rule. If that rule is not written, please write it (it might be in a comment, I'm not asking you to write an essay or FAQ).

Comment: @Rubén Your question becomes much more answerable if you ask 'Can I ask about <specific thing> here?' instead of 'is this broad generic description from the tour still valid'. I guess loads of users here have seen enough and are guessing this is yet another attempt at dragging webapps.se drama over to meta.se, which the regulars here (including me) are (understandably and in my opinion righteously) getting tired off. 1/2

Comment: @Rubén From the help center article [How do I ask a good question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): “**Be specific** If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.”

Comment: If it is not such an attempt, it shouldn't be too hard to just make it a 'Can I ask about <specific thing>?' question. If it is such an attempt, it has no place here. Take it up on WebApps meta or directly contact the CM team, as at this point they're really the only ones with enough power and knowledge to sort this out for you and everyone else involved. Remember to ask them specific questions too though. 2/2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Any question that has to do with the Stack Exchange family of communities is fair game.

IMHO, that's the important sentence; the two bullets below are just examples of that, and not meant to be a complete coverage of what's on-topic here. That is as true in 2024 as it was when Meta Stack Exchange was <s>created</s> [still called Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mso-mse-split/info), though I wasn't around at that time.

Comment: I don't disagree; I would still like to see more answers. P.D. for newbies: I might change the accepted answer if there are more answers.